# Using .Except without case sensitivity C#

Tags: c#

I am working on a project with reads in 2 csv files:

```
var myFullCsv = ReadFile(myFullCsvFilePath);
var masterCsv = ReadFile(csvFilePath);
```

and then creates a new var containing the extra lines that exist in myFullCsv but not master Csv. The code is great because of its simplicity:

```
var extraFilesCsv = myFullCsv.Except(masterCsv);
```

The csv files read in contain data like this:

```
c01.jpg,95182,24f77a1e,\Folder1\FolderA\,
c02.jpg,131088,c17b1f13,\Folder1\FolderA\,
c03.jpg,129485,ddc964ec,\Folder1\FolderA\,
c04.jpg,100999,930ee633,\Folder1\FolderA\,
c05.jpg,101638,b89f1f28,\Folder1\FolderA\,
```

However, I have just found a situation where the case of some characters in each file does not match. For example (JPG in caps):

```
c01.JPG,95182,24f77a1e,\Folder1\FolderA\,
```

If the data is like this then it is not included in extraFilesCsv but I need it to be. Can anybody tell me how I can make this code insensitive to the case of the text?

Edit: Sorry, I forgot that ReadFile was not a standard command. Here is the code:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadFile(string path)
        {
            string line;

            using (var reader = File.OpenText(path))
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    yield return line;
        }
```

Comment: Give us some insight into `ReadFile`. Can you just convert the strings all to lower case? What kind of object does `ReadFile` return?

Comment: What does `ReadFile` method returns, does it returns a collection of Custom object and how `Except` is doing the comparison ?

Comment: You can just use `File.ReadLines` to iterate the lines of a file, if you're using at least .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you've read in both csv files and have a collection of strings representing each file.

You can specify a specific `EqualityComparer` in the call to `Except()`, which instructs on the type of comparison to do between two collections of objects.

You can create your own comparer or, assuming both collections are of strings, try specifying an existing one that ignores case:

```
var extraFilesCsv
    = myFullCsv.Except(masterCsv, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

By default, if you don't specify a comparer, it uses `EqualityComparer<TElement>.Default`, which differs based on the class type you're comparing.

For strings, it first does a straight-up `a==b` comparison by default, which is case-sensitive. *(The exact implementation on the* `string` *class is a little more complicated, but it's probably unnecessary to post it here.)*